# Scrapy crawler's response contains only parts of the website

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

I created a crawler to store all the catalogs on a website like American Eagle. However within the response, there is only a subset of all the catalogs available.

I ran the scrapy shell with: 'scrapy shell "https://www.ae.com/web/browse/category.jsp?catId=cat10025&navdetail=mega:men:c2:p1" '

I then select the appropriate class by 'res = response.css('#facetResults').css('.sProd')'

The len(res) ~ 20. However, if we make a quick visit to the american eagle webpage of MEN/Tops/ you can see there is far more than 20 items available.

I have tried to change the css selector but to no success.. Please help thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compare the HTML code from your browser's development tool with the original source code, you can see that whereas the browser HTML console shows all the items, the orinal code only displays 20 of them.

All the catalog information is stored in a JS variable called `category_json`, and that is alwais present in the body without needing to interact with page.

I would recomend you to retrieve that variable and extract the information from it, I made some test with this code using the scrapy shell:

```
In [1]: import re, json

In [2]: data_json = re.search('category_json = ({.*})', response.body).group(1)

In [3]: data = json.loads(data_json)

In [4]: products = data['availablePrds'].keys()

In [5]: data['availablePrds'][products[0]]
Out[5]:
{u'availableColorIds': [],
 u'brandName': u'AEO',
 u'bundleCatId': u'',
 u'classId': u'0164',
 u'colorImageSelectionData': {u'100': {u'colorNam
   u'colorPrdId': u'0164_3898_100',
   u'factoryExclusive': False,
   u'greatGift': False,
   u'imgViews': [u'_f', u'_b'],
   u'isAvailable': True,
   u'newArrival': True,
   u'webExclusive': False}},
 u'contextRoot': u'web',
 u'defaultURL': u'/browse/product_details.jsp',
 u'firstAvailableColorPrdId': u'0164_3898_100',
 u'hasBundle': False,
 u'isAvailable': False,
 u'isClearance': False,
 u'isGWP': False,
 u'isHazMat': False,
 u'listPrice': u'\u20ac22.36 EUR',
 u'marketingMessage': u'Buy One Get One 50% Off',
 u'prdId': u'0164_3898',
 u'prdName': u'AEO NYC Graphic T-Shirt',
 u'rating': u'',
 u'salePrice': u'\u20ac22.36 EUR',
 u'styleId': u'3898'}
```

If you loop over the variable you can retrieve all the information you need for each product and yield the item.

Comment: Awesome suggestion. Will try!